# QGIS Split lines with lines - aggregated features split into multiple segments

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro

I am trying to split a line layer into parts with lines from another line layer with the tool "Split with lines".
I am working with a layer that was previously aggregated using an attribute. I did it in QGIS. And also tested the procedure with a layer created in ArcGIS with Dissolve tool.
However, the tool gives unexpected results.
Despite of split features at line intersections, the aggregated layer splits back to the geometry it had before aggregation.
Does any one can give explanation to this odd behaviour? Or maybe this is just a bug in the tool?
Any solutions?

[image]